# com.sun.mirror.apt API

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and I am getting an error via Eclipse on the following lines:

```
import com.sun.mirror.apt.AnnotationProcessorFactory;
import com.sun.mirror.apt.AnnotationProcessor;
import com.sun.mirror.apt.AnnotationProcessorEnvironment;
```

The error is "The import com.sun.mirror cannot be resolved".

How do I fix this error?

Comment: "The import some.package.namespace cannot be resolved" indicates, that the library you refer to is not present during compilition (= not in your classpath)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To the point: just put it in the classpath (buildpath, in Eclipse). You can download it [here](https://aptmirrorapi.dev.java.net).

However, this use is not really recommended. Rather use the standard API classes and methods in the [`javax.annotation.processing` API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/package-summary.html) which are already inside the standard Java SE API. It will "behind the scenes" use the *right* classes for the desired tasks.

Comment: Where can I download this library?

Answer (score 5):

**Deprecated**

apt tool and API have been **deprecated** as of JDK 7.
Mention on: https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/apt_api_files

To resolve you can import tools.jar %JDK JAVA%\lib\tools.jar.

In my case "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_01\lib\tools.jar"

Comment: I think more standard is %JAVA_HOME%

Answer (score 1):

also the answer by BalusC is correct but the link is dead and there is simpler solution 
in Sun JDK both 1.5 and 1.5 there is tools.jar in the /lib/ add it to the class path it all there.

Answer (score 0):

Though it's deprecated ,if you want to give it a try like dealing with a sample of a book,you may download the zip file of `apt-mirror-api-0.1.jar` [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadaptmirrorapi01jar.htm), and then just build path in your IDE. For eclipse,just right click the `JRE System Library`-->`Build Path`-->`Configure Build Path`-->`Add External JARs` and finally find your downloaded jar file and apply it.